# Razor_imu_9dof can't see my Sparkfun IMU (14001)?

Tags: ros, imu, razor-imu-9dof, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 (x86).

I've followed the instructions for `razor_imu_9dof`, for the Razor SEN-14001 M0 board from Sparkfun. I flashed the AHRS firmware, and installed all the relevant ROS packages. I am able to see the IMU spewing data on `/dev/ttyACM0`, by running `cat` or `screen`.

However, when I run

```
roslaunch razor_imu_9dof razor-pub-and-display.launch
```

I just get the error:

```
[ERROR] [1525842655.072800]: IMU not found at port /dev/ttyACM0. Did you specify the correct port in the launch file?
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to troubleshoot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290736/razor_imu_9dof-can%27t-see-my-sparkfun-imu-(14001)?/) by [roach374](https://answers.ros.org/users/35039/roach374/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2018-05-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-05-09**:
Just to check you're not trying to run the launch file at the same time as viewing the output using cat or screen are you?

**Comment by [roach374](https://answers.ros.org/users/35039/roach374/) on 2018-05-09**:
No, I did that separately, add part of my naive attempt to troubleshoot. One thing I did notice though, the /dev/ttyACM0 device is owned by root/dialout. Maybe it's a permissions issue? I tried running sudo roslaunch, but it barfed with "unrecognized command".

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-05-09**:
if cat can read from the port then it should be fine. You can always use [chmod](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm) to set the permissions of /dev/ttyACM0 . Note they will be reset every time to plug it in.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-05-09**:
We've got a few of these in our lab, I can check what the output should look like tomorrow so you can check the firmware is correct.

**Comment by [roach374](https://answers.ros.org/users/35039/roach374/) on 2018-05-09**:
I think I've figured it out. It WAS a permissions issue. I added my user account to the dialout group, and things seem to be working fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turned out to be a permissions issue. I added my user account to the dialout group, and everything started working.

---

Originally posted by [roach374](https://answers.ros.org/users/35039/roach374/) with karma: 36 on 2018-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roach374](https://answers.ros.org/users/35039/roach374/) on 2018-05-09**:
This is the answer, but I can't accept it, since I don't have enough karma.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-05-10**:
Glad you got this working